# How to handle a big5 personality traits task

Tags: regression, classification, psychology, multilabel

I have a dataset consists of N tweets annotated with the big 5 personality traits (`extroverted`, `stable`, `agreeable`, `conscientious`, and `open`). Each category represented by a real number.

I want to predict the score of each personality trait for the documents, but I don't know how should I handle the task.

One possibility is to split it into 5 different regression tasks, but then a classifier could miss the correlations between the 5 classes (e.g. a document written by someone `extroverted` has a higher probability that the author is also `open`).

Another one is to apply a multi-label approach, but I don't think that is possible since this way is applied when there are labels and not real values (classification instead of regression), no?